# Why do I get "not in executable format: Success" from gdbserver, but everything works fine in gdb?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, clang, bazel

When trying to run an executable on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04), I can run the executable under `gdb`:

```
gdb ./bazel-bin/drake/systems/sensors/rgbd_camera_test
```

However, if I try to run the executable under `gdbserver` and connect, it's a different story:

```
tty1$ gdbserver localhost:9999 ./bazel-bin/drake/systems/sensors/rgbd_camera_test

tty2$ gdb
(gdb) target remote localhost:9999
Remote debugging using localhost:9999
Reading ${BAZEL_ROOT}/bazel-out/clang-3.9-linux-dbg/bin/drake/systems/sensors/rgbd_camera_test from remote target...
warning: File transfers from remote targets can be slow. Use "set sysroot" to access files locally instead.
"target:${BAZEL_ROOT}/bazel-out/clang-3.9-linux-dbg/bin/drake/systems/sensors/rgbd_camera_test": not in executable format: Success
```

I am using `bazel` (0.4.5) with `clang-3.9`. I get the same results if I use:

```
bazel run --run_under=gdb //drake/systems/sensors:rgbd_camera_test`
```

and `--run_under 'gdbserver localhost:9999'`.

Answer (score 4):

The issue was that my binary was too large for remote transfer. I realized this by reading the above hint from `gdb`, to call `set sysroot` in `gdb`. Using this, I can debug the executable using `gdbserver`.

Note that this can be added to your `~/.gdbinit` if you will \only be doing local debugging. In my situation, I use `gdbserver` when debugging with CLion (as sometimes directly debugging does not seem to work...)